# STRIPE "Cannot accept the Terms of Service on behalf of Standard and Express connected accounts"

Tags: express, stripe-payments

I am using stripe and I have connected an express account.
I have updated the contented account information but it is still restricted as It said I have to accept tos ( terms of service) ni order to enable all functions.
The api i am using to update is returning me this error

> "message": "You cannot accept the Terms of Service on behalf of Standard and Express connected accounts.",
> "type": "invalid_request_error",

I have followed the link [stipeupdate](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/updating-accounts#tos-acceptance)

How do I resolve this issue ?

Comment: You should reach out to Stripe support for this: https://support.stripe.com/contact

Comment: I did, but their response is even more confusing and a time taking process. Thats why I am here

Comment: @MuhammadUsama did u find a solution to this problem ?

Answer (score 8):

Based on the link you posted it seems that you are trying to run the code below:

```
const account = await stripe.accounts.update(
  '{{CONNECTED_STRIPE_ACCOUNT_ID}}',
  {
    tos_acceptance: {
      date: Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000),
      ip: request.connection.remoteAddress, // Assumes you're not using a proxy
    },
  }
);
```

The error is explicit. You can't run that code unless the onboarding account is Custom... not Express or Standard

Answer (score 0):

Stripe do not provide such API service till now where we can create standard or express account with accepted terms and services and fully enabled to use.

Comment: Are you sure? "Each [business entity](https://stripe.com/docs/issuing/connect) that uses issued cards **must be represented by a Custom connected** account." *This is not to be confused with Customized issuable cards and its [Standard issuing](https://stripe.com/issuing#pricing) version.* Although perhaps *you are right and it's just that: the **`company` structure must then be Custom type** to issue while individuals can issue*, "**Create connected accounts with Issuing capabilities**; [b]efore you create Custom connected accounts for your Issuing integration in live mode, []."